# How to change name of jrxml file?

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to change the name of my JasperReports's report from "Test Report  Detail " to  "Test Reagent Detail"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. right click on the report from left panel and click "properties"
2. the first column is your report name, you can click on the icon "..." and it will open your report name that can easily be edited.
3. use the "save as" option to save the renamed report if necessary.

Comment: > thanks  it's working But need to Rename the  .jrxml file

Comment: like i already mentioned in point 3, you can use "save as" option and mentioned the name "Test Reagent Detail" while saving and simply delete the old file.